# Publishers and Subscribers in ros

Tags: ros, path, package, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have created a package in my ros_workspace(directory),and I have tried to write a simple publisher into the "Codeblocks" software, in the package directory, but it seems that the software cannot compile the program at all because it cannot find the headers needed. Although, the headers exist, I found them and add the paths to the program, but there are lots of them, I can't everytime add 10 or more paths for a publisher only. Does the fact that I did not create beginner_tutorials package with turtle node and all that first, matters?is something in those files needed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12615/publishers-and-subscribers-in-ros/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2012-01-12**:
Could you perhaps post the error(s) you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check out [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#CodeBlocks)?

---

Originally posted by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) with karma: 345 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when you created the package doing roscreate-pkg did you list all of the correct dependencies? If not, you can add more dependencies in the CMakeCache.txt file. This may be a reason why you are unable to compile (it has been the reason for me numerous times).

---

Originally posted by [baseballmvp27](https://answers.ros.org/users/1558/baseballmvp27/) with karma: 31 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1